# vb.net 2012 and crystal report 13 paragraph indention on formula field

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I want to create and formula field that will display in a paragraph form and I need some indention to it. When I use HTML on paragraph, the indention style won't work.

Here's my code:

```
if ({view_clearance.purpose} <> "") 
then  "<head><style> p
  {text-indent: 2.0em; } </style></head><body> <p>  text here " + " " +
  {view_clearance.purpose} + "  " + "<br> <br>  <u> text here </u>" +
  " " + {@date}  + " " + " </p></body></html> " 
else ""
```

Comment: What indentation are you trying

Comment: a paragraph indention on the formula field